# Compare two ranges and insert value from third range if duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

**Intro**

I have an excel sheet with a large amount of rows. Column A and column D contain dates, where column A contains multiple of the same date, and column D only contains one of each date - both in the same time span. In other words, every date in column D exists multiple times in column A.

**The problem**

My problem is that I would like to compare column A and column D, and IF the value in column A is equal to the value in column D, THEN insert the value of column E in column B for that given row in column A.

**Context**

I pulled a large .csv containing information about the XEO option index on S&P100. I have to separately pulled a .csv containing the relevant daily quotes for the S&P100. Now I have to insert the price quote of the S&P100 for the relevant date matching the date of the XEO option price quote.

Below is a snapshot of the Excel sheet.

[image: Snapshot of sheet]

Column A runs to A1048576.
Column D and E runs to D859 and E859.

I have already written some of the code, but I am missing something in the Loop (please see below).

```
Sub CrossReferenceInsertValue() 

Dim lastCell As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim rngCell As Range

Set ws1 as Worksheet
ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each rngCell In ws1.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws1.Range("D2:D" & lastRow), rngCell) = 1 Then
        'something here I cannot figure out. 
    End If

End sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use a vlookup formula in column B?

`=VLOOKUP(A:A,D:E,2)` should do the trick. No loop no VBA.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Formula in column B looks for value A in column D and pulls value from column E. Column D needs to be unique values otherwise it will pull the first one found.</sup>*

If this has to be done whithin a process in VBA just write that formula with VBA:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B100").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A:A,D:E,2)"
```

If you need constant values and no formulas convert the formula into values after writing it.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B100")
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A:A,D:E,2)"
    .Value = .Value  '‹~~ converts formula into values
End With
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there are not always the same values in B to a given value in A. In your example, however, there are. Thus, a removal of the duplicates would suffice. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RalfS the OP states that the dates exists only once in column D, so a simple VLookUP as Pᴇʜ is showing would suffice.

Comment: Hey Peh, worked like a charm. Thanks. Used the VLOOKUP function like you suggested, I guessed I just tried to overcomplicate the task with VBA.